# Is it possible to apply react-konva into React Native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, canvas, react-konva

I saw react-konva bounce ball sample https://codesandbox.io/s/5qvyyyjrx from google and I tried to apply it into my React Native app.

But no luck, I getting this error **invariant violation view config not found for name div** which is from **Stage (import { Stage } from "react-konva";)**.

May I know any way to solve this problem and react-konva can be apply in React Native?

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It the current moment `react-konva@16.12.0` and `konva@4.0.0` are designed to use a web platform only.

You can't use it for React Native.

Comment: @lavrton Did you have any project where you ported the web app to mobile with Ionic/Cordova? If yes, was the experience ok?

Comment: @GustavoMorais no, I don't have personal experience with porting into Phonegap. But build many mobile-web versions. So far, so good.